# How do you kill the final boss of Guacamelee?

Tags: guacamelee

This Skeleton Face Guy (Caraca?) instantly owns me.

Here's the list of things that you have to deal with all at once in this battle:

- He only telegraphs his upcoming attack a few frames before it lands. I have not yet been able to determine how to dodge any of his attacks, even if I could figure out which one is coming in time.
- He seems to randomly switch between the world of the living and the world of the dead. So in addition to having a fraction of a second to figure out how to dodge, you also have to in that same time figure out whether you need to switch worlds.
- He also seems to randomly change the color of his shield. So in addition to dodging his attack and making sure you're in the right world in a fraction of a second, you also have to figure out what attack to use (which you may not always be in the right position for, given whatever dodging maneuver you have to use) before he disappears, less than a second later.

Seriously? There has to be a trick to this. Nothing else in the game has even approached this level of insane precision and instantaneous reaction.

How do you even *touch* this guy, let alone kill him?

Comment: Wait until you beat him, then have to fight against his demon form. He gets somewhat easier (since you can actually predict his moves this time), but he deals a lot more damage with each attack. I died maybe 20-50 times before I beat him for good. Guacamelee will forever remain in my memory for being hard, yet fair and fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calaca only has two attacks: the Side Claw and Sky Stomp. Both can be avoided by jumping diagonally, so once you get the timing down (it's pretty consistent) you can dodge before he even appears. I don't currently recall whether you can simply roll through his attacks; if so things get even easier, though you have to pay attention to roll towards him so the extended shockwave won't hit you once the roll is done.

Once you can dodge consistently, you can hit back. If he's in the wrong world, don't bother trying to attack him unless you have good reflexes, just swap after dodging and wait for the next attack (he tends to stay in the same word for a few hits in a row, and I don't think he ever switches after only one attack). It is sometimes a pain to notice the correct shield colour in time, but I've never really had a problem with it. Your attack will still hit even if he's almost done teleporting away; as long as the shield is visible you can hit him. Attacks that break shields also do damage, so you don't need to concern yourself with trying to hit him after the shield goes down. Then use a roll to cancel your attack's ending lag and get ready for the next dodge.

Calaca has 300 HP. Assuming you hit him once per cycle with the correct attack, that's 20 damage per cycle (he only uses red, green, and blue shields, and your red/green/blue attacks all deal 20 damage), meaning you need a minimum of 15 cycles to defeat him. On the other hand, his attacks deal 50 damage to you; you start the game with 80 HP with every 3 Heart Chunks increasing it by 20, so by getting about 7 chunks you can increase the number of hits you can take by 1.

Comment: Don't think you can roll through his attacks unfortunately.

Comment: You can't roll through the shock wave because the wave stays out longer than your roll does.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part calaca will be easily avioded by jumping diagonally to a wall then to the other side repeatedly an he will always hit from swipes when and wher you land last only attack him when he has blue/red shields never green because of the lag it has but still punch him with the green shild because it will build up intenso which u need for demon form never for first stage don't worry about health in first stage as soon as you get to second stage it saves and restores health, stamina, and maybe intenso

Answer (score 0):

It's way more easy than it seems. Just move and roll the WHOLE time from left to right and right to left. Keep moving and never jump. If you do it well, Calaca will nearly never touch you.

Once you get used to that, just attack him just after he attacked. As others have pointed out, you can still touch him even if he is disappearing. In all cases, you will be rolling away from him (because you are always rolling even if he does not attack) so you have to go back in his direction to hit him.

If you feel you are too far, don't go for it, otherwise you will miss him and he will get you when he reappears. Play it safe, and you should win easily. Avoid to attack him when he is green, the attack is too slow because you have to jump.